# WCF Restful services with Android , iOS and WPF Clients

Tags: android, ios, wcf, rest, notifications

All ,

We are developing a client Server application based application . The Server application which will be developed as WCF Services collects data from some instruments and stores it in a database.

The client applications shall query the WCF Services and  can search / view data , generate reports , graphs etc. The clients can be any of the following

**1 - WPF based windows Application**

**2 - ASP.NET MVC  browser web application**

**3 - ASP.NET MVC  Mobile web application**

**4 - Native Android apps**

**5 - Native iOS apps**

Our plan is the following

**1) Stateless REST based WCF Service Contracts using a token based authentication for  search / view data , generate reports , graphs etc.**

**2) A Service Contract with  WSDualHttpBinding with reliable session call back control for 
pushing notifications to .NET Client**

**3) Native approaches like SignalR or Web sockets for push notifications in case of Android / iOS native applications**

is this a good  approach

Comment: Even I'm looking for the answer of this query, please suggest if anyone has answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think first one makes sense. You should also consider about the security of web service transaction.You can read about oauth.